# sending data as json from ajax to express server causes preflight cors error

Tags: ajax, express

This question has been asked a gazillion times. I've read the mozilla documentation and looked through so many answers my eyes hurt.

In my ajax call I have this:

```
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
            data: {name: "test"},
            contentType: 'application/json',
  url: 'https://example.com:8443',
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
```

in my express server my server.js file is this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.myData);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure World!</h1>');
});
```

from my understanding I'm properly making the ajax call with dataType: 'json', and contentType 'application/json'.

Also I'm setting acess control allow origin to * which should allow me to have any domain hit my server.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I get this error:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was a dumb one.  In express js this is incorrect:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

The settings should actually be like this `'',''` not `':'`

```
The correct syntax that worked is this:
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
```

EDIT: Using * is a security risk but in this case it's one server testing on another both of which I own.  When going live I would set * to example.com

Comment: setting ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is security risk for your app. Consider using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors in order to allow only your trusted origins.

Comment: Updated @Pranay Tripathi